# FileReader output saved to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filereader

I would like to ask you, if it is possible to iterate through list of file inputs and save the results in one array. Here is bit of my code.
Also I use AngularJS if it helps...

**HTML**

```
        <input type="file" id="file1">
        <input type="file" id="file2">
        <button id="saveBtn">Save</button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
results = []; // array for storing results
/*file inputs*/
inputs = [document.getElementById('file1'), document.getElementById('file2')];

function readFile() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length(); i++) {
        if (inputs[i].files && inputs[i].files[0]) {
            var FR = new FileReader();
            FR.onload = function (event) {
                results[i] = event.target.result; //array where I would like to store results
            };
            FR.readAsDataURL(inputs[0].files[0]);
        }
    }
}
//here I would like to write down all results
var btn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
btn.onclick = function() {
readFile();
for(var i=0; i < inputs.length(); i++) {
   console.log(results[i]);
 }
}
```

When I run this code, as result I get 'undefined'.
Do you guys have any ideas how to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: would you provide jsfiddle for this...

Comment: Maybe your for loop is executed before the `readFile` function is executed? If not, you could use `FR.error` to debug if there is some trouble reading the files.

Comment: when is readFile function called ?

Comment: No that is not the problem. In code a have an event where I call the readFile() and than I make a loop. But I wanted to make it short here so I skipped it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the point that Niek Vandael makes in his answer; the fact that you are trying to show information before it has completed loading, there are a few other issues with your code.

```
input.lengths()
```

should be

```
input.lengths
```

lengths it's not a method. That causes an error when I test the code (in Chrome).

You also read the same data over and over;

```
FR.readAsDataURL(inputs[0].files[0]);
```

should probably be

```
FR.readAsDataURL(inputs[i].files[0]);
```

So, here's another take on it. I added a couple of vars to keep track of items loaded and how many there are to load, then call the function to display the data once it has been loaded.

```
results = []; // array for storing results
/*file inputs*/
inputs = [document.getElementById('file1'), document.getElementById('file2')];

//here I would like to write down all results
var btn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
var inputCount;
var filesLoaded = 0;

function readFile() {
    inputCount = Number(inputs.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < inputCount ; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].files && inputs[i].files[0]) {
            var FR = new FileReader();
            FR.onload = function (event) {
                results.push(event.target.result); //array where I would like to store results
                filesLoaded++;
                if (filesLoaded == inputCount) {
                    showResult();
                }
            };
            FR.readAsDataURL(inputs[i].files[0]);
        }
    }
}

btn.onclick = function () {
    readFile();
}

function showResult() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length ; i++) {
        console.log(results[i]);
    }
}
```

There are a few more things to think about, such as validating that files have been selected etc, but I guess it's kind of out of the scope here.

Comment: Sorry for my silly mistakes. This worked just right :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

onLoad gets executed when the FileReader has loaded, so after you write your log statements.

Try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/s17Lmc21/1/

```
results = []; // array for storing results
/*file inputs*/
inputs = [document.getElementById('file1'),     document.getElementById('file2')];

function readFile() {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].files && inputs[i].files[0]) {
            var FR = new FileReader();
            FR.onload = function (event) {
                results[i] = event.target.result; //array where I would like     to store results
                console.log(results[i]);
            };
            FR.readAsDataURL(inputs[0].files[0]);
        }
    }
}
//here I would like to write down all results
var btn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
btn.onclick = function() {
readFile();
}
```